# Update with regex part of the string with delimeters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a lot of records in file in format

```
=text.GROUP1.GROUP2.GROUP_TO_RENAME.GROUP3.GROUP4.GROUP5
```

or

```
=[text.GROUP1.GROUP2.GROUP_TO_RENAME.GROUP3.GROUP4].GROUP5
```

and also records with completely different format.
I need to rename GROUP_TO_RENAME to another based on it's value (eg CAT -> Kitty, Mouse -> Jerry) and do not touch some groups (TOM for example).

I want to get via regex 2 things - name of this GROUP_TO_RENAME (to know if it should be changed) and the way to replace this GROUP_TO_RENAME with the new value.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is this pure ambition? Or a real task? Why do you need C# for if you want to move the logic in a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it by using a dictionary:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("CAT", "Kitty");
        dict.Add("MOUSE", "Jerry");

        var lines = File.ReadAllText("input.txt");
        var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=(^=\[?(?:\w*?\.){3}))\w*?(?=(\.\w*?\]?){3}$?)",
            RegexOptions.Multiline |
            RegexOptions.Compiled);

        var result = regex.Replace(lines, m =>
            dict.ContainsKey(m.Value) ? dict[m.Value] : m.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will fail for '=[text.testName2.CAT.CAT.testName3.testName4].testName5' - I need to replace only one group, not all satisfying the criteria

Comment: And for =[text.testName2.sample.CAT.testName3.testName4]'it  fails too. Number of groups is important too

Comment: Well, the information from your comments is NOT in your question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Still fails for '=[text.testName2.sample.CAT.testName3.testName4]'

Comment: How does it fail? I get: `=[text.testName2.sample.Kitty.testName3.testName4]`. What is the expected output?

Comment: I mean it should not be updated - only records with exact number of groups should be processed(last group testName5 missed).

Comment: Updated. Let me know if there are other issues.

Comment: Excellent! If text in '=[text.' is static value like 'animal' - how it will look like? It's just for my knowledge, I've marked it as answer.

Comment: It has no influence in this case. `\w*` matches both `text` and `animal`.

Comment: Could you please display eli5 why with regex 'text.[\W|_|\w]+.\w+.\w+.\w+' and input '=(text.a.b.b.d.e.f.g-text.h.i.j.k.l.m.n)' it catch only one and the whole strin, not twice a smaller part?